# Example where $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, but for all $p\in[1,2)\cup(2,\infty]$ $f\notin L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis

Construct an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$, but such that for all $p\in[1,2)\cup(2,\infty]$ $f\notin L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$.

I can see how to go about constructing  $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ and $f\notin L^p$ for $p>1$, but this one asks for $f\in L^2$ Or is there a general construction for any specific $p$?

Comment: If $f \in L^1$, then $\sqrt{|f|} \in L^2$, so the construction is pretty close....

Comment: $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(|x|)\,n^{-5/2}$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1380762) will work.